# Where are the dconf profiles?

Tags: application-development, dconf, gsettings

The [dconf System Administrator Guide](https://live.gnome.org/dconf/SystemAdministrators) says that "dconf stores its profiles in text files in `/etc/dconf/profile/`" but on my 11.10 Ubuntu laptop, there is no `/etc/dconf` directory.

Have profiles been deprecated or where are they now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not confused about which dconf you are using.

dconf takes the approach that, in the default configuration, there should be no files in `/etc/`.  You only add files there if you want to make changes to the default configuration.  For that reason it's true that `/etc/dconf/` doesn't exist by default.  You need to create it and populate it according to the documentation on that wiki page in order to setup profiles.

You can indicate a dconf profile in another directory. For example:

```
export DCONF_PROFILE=/home/user/mydconfprofile
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan, that makes sense.  I have abandoned using Unbuntu/Unity on the laptop, issues: no wifi indicator in systray, no hibernate/suspend and excessive power consumption.